# Declare two or more casper in a single script

Tags: javascript, authentication, session-cookies, casperjs

What I want to do is to declare two caspers, the two will login to a certain site, one will act as an admin and the other one will act as a typical user. And I want to do it in a single script.

Is it possible to declare two or more casper in a single script? 
just like this one:

```
var casper1 = require("casper").create({
    verbose: true,  timeout: null
});

var casper2 = require("casper").create({
    verbose: true,  timeout: null
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That heavily depends on how the web site handles sessions. If this is done through a unique ID in every request as a request parameter, then this is possible. But as soon as cookies are used, this is not possible.

CasperJS is like a browser. You can have multiple tabs (`casper` instances), but the session is handled by the browser (PhantomJS). Even if you have multiple `casper` instances, they operate on the same cookies, so you cannot be logged in as a user and as an admin at the same time. This is because PhantomJS handles the cookies and even if you have multiple `casper` instances, there is only one phantomjs process underneath.

If the admin interface is on another domain, this multiple `casper` instances should work. The rule of thumb is, if you can login in a single browser window with multiple tabs, you can do it with multiple `casper` instances.

So, if they are on the same domain and cookies are used, you would need to do this with different scripts.

Other questions that might interest you:

- [How to test two interacting browsers (e.g. chat app)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24315512)
- [How to open a new tab in CasperJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24880671)