# Require a bower dependency as a nodejs module

Tags: node.js, bower, casperjs

I would like to call the nodejs require function on a node module installed as a bower dependency (found in bower.json and not installed with npm).

bower.json:

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "casperjs": "git@github.com:n1k0/casperjs.git",
```

actual code snippet I want to use:

```
    var casper = require('casperjs').create();
```

Is it possible ? I tried to call also (targeting the node module from the bower component directory):

```
    var casper = require('../casperjs').create();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CasperJS is not a node module. It is only installed through npm for convenience. You should look into [SpookyJS](https://github.com/WaterfallEngineering/SpookyJS) or [Nightmare](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare) which are actual node modules that provide a high level API for web automation.

CasperJS gets most of its modules from PhantomJS (or SlimerJS) which are similar, but distinct from the node modules (mainly `fs`). So problems like these arise: [Error: Cannot find module 'libxmljs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24602466/error-cannot-find-module-libxmljs)

Comment: Interesting, then how can I use the answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604611/what-does-then-really-mean-in-casperjs/11957919#11957919 ? I would like to use "var casper = require('casper').create();" to run multiple casper instances in parallel, see also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/casperjs/Scx4Cjqp7hE/discussion.

Comment: Write your CasperJS script and [spawn](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) multiple instances.

Comment: You can also look into [those](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24880671/how-to-open-a-new-tab-in-casperjs) [few](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437512/running-multiple-instances-of-casperjs) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315512/how-to-test-two-interacting-browsers-e-g-chat-app).

Comment: Since I call my scrpit with the casperjs commandline, I ended up using "new casper.constructor()" instead of "require('casper').create();" it's the only thing I got working so far (the tricky part seems to be my core logic is in code exposed via a nodejs exports statement). Thanks for the hints !